# how to use (read) google pre-trained word2vec model file?

Tags: python, classification, keras, word2vec

I am trying to apply open() function in keras to use Google news-vectors-negative300.bin which is a pre-trained file via word2vec such as GloVe, but after downloading GloVe it contains 4 files with txt prefix vs the Google news-vectors-negative300.bin folder contains a file with binary prefix namely 'data' which is 3.4 GB.
I write the commands on ubuntu 17.10 via keras with tensorflow backend on spyder with python 3.5, and after implementing the command it gave me this error:

> ```
> File "/home/mary/anaconda3/envs/virenv/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
>   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 19: invalid start byte.
> ```

the written code is as follow: `f = open('data')`.

I have already implemented the same code successfully when I applied
`f = open('glove.6B.100d.txt')`.

What is the main problem?

Comment: Have you seen the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22216076/5120235).

Answer (score 2):

I have searched about it and fixed the error through these steps:
you should load the "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz" file at first then extract it by this command in Ubuntu: `gunzip -k GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz.` [ manually extracting is never recommended]. Secondly, you should apply these commands in python 3:

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('./model/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

I hope it will be useful.